# Laravel 4.2: In functionTest case /start/global.php is loaded after service providers

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4.2

We are facing a problem in Laravel 4.2 where our `/start/global.php` is loaded/executed after some ServiceProvider. In our ServiceProvider `public function register()` and `public function boot()` are called before `/start/global.php` loaded/executed. This only happends while running our application tests via phpUnit. If we run our applicatoin via Browser on our Server the sequence of loading is correct.

#### TestCase.php:

```
namespace app\tests\base;

class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;
        $testEnvironment = 'testing';

        return require __DIR__ . '/../../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }
}
```

#### phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/base/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

---

We looked deeper into the codes and recognized that `$app->booted()` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` is executed after `public function register()` and `public function boot()` (ServiceProvider).

How could we force the testing environment to load our application in the correct way? - Also refer: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle

#### Full codes for reproduction can be downloaded here: https://github.com/linslin/laravel-42-test-boot-sequence